# Timer in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

My users create a new table cell every time a `textFieldShouldReturn` method is called. I want to add a timer to that cell as a subtitle so every cell will have a different timer. And when the timer runs out, I need the cell to destroy itself.

I'm only looking for directions here, how do you think I should go about it?

Comment: Cell is a view and therefor not the place to store data, timers, etc. There should be in your model, the model should feed the view, table view cell in your case.

Comment: You can display timer on a label and you have to reload table on every second.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "add a timer to that cell as a subtitle". Are you wanting to show how much time they have left before it will destroy itself?

Comment: But if there is too much data and you reload the cells every second it could slow everything down and maybe scrolling wont work fine anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do that is to create an CountDown class and a CountDownDelegate protocol.

The CountDown class will be responsive to handle the timer and to call a method on the delegate when countdown reaches 0. `countDownDidReachesZero:(CountDown *)countDown`

Then your UIViewController (or UITableViewController) keep the list of countdown in an array and conforms to CountDownDelegate.

```
- (void)countDownDidReachesZero:(CountDown *)countDown
{
NSMutableArray *array = [self.countdowns mutableCopy];
[array removeObject:countDown];
self.countdowns = array; //if property is set with copy flag
[self.tableView reloadData]; // get index and remove cell with effect would be better
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{
NSMutableArray *array = [self.countdowns mutableCopy];
[array addObject:[[CountDown alloc] init]];
self.countdowns = array;
[self.tableView reloadData]; //or add the cell with effect
return YES;
}
```

For updating the detailLabel.text you can also do it with your CountDownDelegate protocol. A good thing to do should be to have only one static NSTimer which update all countDown.